# How to get a random string from an array of strings?

Tags: java, arrays, random

I got a `String[]` from which I want to get a random value. I try to put that logic in another method. This is my code so far.

```
public static void main(String[]args) {
   String [] S = {"aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee","ggg", "hhh", "iii", "kkk"};
}

public String get () {
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {

    }
}
```

I need random strings out of array `S` with the method `get()`, but I really don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you'll have to move the S array to be an instance variable or a static variable, because currently it's local to your main method, and can't be accessed from your `get` method.

Then you can get a random String this way :

```
private Random rnd = new Random();
public String get ()
{
   return S[rnd.nextInt(S.length)];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice. but if I want to S to remain static variable will it be any other way to write the code.

Comment: @Rslh currently S is not a static variable, it's a local variable of the static main method. If you want to keep it there, you can pass it as an argument to the get() method.

Comment: Thanks I think I need to review the concept of this language again

Answer (score 0):

You can use `java.util.Random` to generate random things. However, keep in mind that, it is not secure, not really random.

You can get random `char`s from the array `S`:

```
String randomString = ""; 
Random rand = new Random();
for(int i=0;i<=4;i++)
{
    randomString += S[rand.nextInt(S.length())].charAt(0);
}

System.out.println(randomString);
```

Answer (score 0):

you do not need loop in get() method you need to generate a random number below the length of the original array and say return S[RANDOM_NUMBER]

**EDIT**

let the get method takes a parameter of String[]